# How to create a parallax website in html (why will my bg image not cover the whole screen?)

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am creating a parallax bg but the bg image does not cover the full screen could anyone tell me how to fix it? This is what I have as far as the parallax..

```
    <style>
    .parallax { 
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("rocket-2680282_1920 (1).jpg");
        /* Set a specific height */
        height: 1078px; 
        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: initial;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
   </style>
```

here is the website if you want to see what I mean [link](http://galaxyrocket.me)

Comment: `margin: 0;` on `body` to override browser's default margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following to body element in css:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

This will fix it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

it look like your `body` have a `margin` try adding this to your css :

```
body{
 margin:0px;
}
```